# Why I am not able to import sass files

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass, laravel-mix

I am using Laravel with react and I just simply want to include a single scss file in webpack.mix.js and in that file I am refering to all other scss files

But I am not able to make it work , I have been struggling with it for hours but all in vain :(
It is comping and all but the result is an empty css file

webpack.mix.js:

```
mix.react("resources/js/index.js", "public/js")
    .sass("resources/js/utils/app.scss", "public/css")
    .extract();
```

app.scss:

```
$primary: #1e2258;
$dark: #555;
$secondary: #999;

@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Farro&display=swap");
@import "../components/layouts/styles/all.scss"; //THIS IS THE FILE !!

body {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    font-family: Farro, Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #ccc, #eee); 
}
........
```

all.scss:

```
@import "Landing";
@import "about";
@import "./contact.scss";
@import "./nav.scss";
@import "./product-card.scss";
@import "./product.scss";
@import "./scrollTopBtn.scss";
```

is this a problem with mix or is the problem with my code ??????????
if there is another approach please tell me

Comment: Did you try using actual `.sass` files instead of `.scss` files?

Comment: You don’t need to use the scss extension when importing.

Comment: As you can see I tried without the ext but it did'nt help either